# Echange 2013 internal server IP and name on message header

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I have a server with Exchange 2013.
Each message that is sent externally contains the IP and the internal server name.
How can I hide this IP and internal name? Because some domains that reject the messages because of this with the following error:

*...local>: Helo command rejected: ACCESS DENIED. Your email was rejected because the sending mail server does not identify itself correctly (.local)*

It could be probably some send-connector configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reliable mail delivery, among other things, your Exchange server should identify itself to other mail servers with a FQDN (fully qualified domain name) and not with its Active Directory domain name.

Both the **forward and reverse DNS** records with that FQDN should  match the effective public ip-address that will be used when your mail server connects to a remote mail server. (If you're not sure which IP-address that is: send a message from your own Exchange account  to [`ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com`](https://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability) which will give you that ip-address and other useful info.)

AFAIK You indeed set the FQDN   on the send connector https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/set-sendconnector?view=exchange-ps

```
Set-SendConnector "Contoso.com Send Connector" -Fqdn mail.contoso.com
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to send an email successfully with this change of send connector.